# Regex Replace Everything Between Dashes Including New lines?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I have the following dashed markers and I want to replace everything in between if `$("#AddInfo")` is not empty. If `$("#AddInfo")` is empty then I want to delete everything in between the markers. It works the first time when you add some content but then the second time you call the function e.g. if `$("#AddInfo")` has new content or is empty then nothing changes between the markers?

```
var msg = "some stuff --- ---  more stuff";

if ($("#AddInfo").val())
  msg = msg.replace(/---[^]---/, "---\n" + $("#AddInfo").val() + "\n---");
else
  msg = msg.replace(/---[^]---/, "--- ---");
}
```

Comment: What do you want to match with `[^]`?

Comment: Under what event are you calling this code?

Comment: @Toto `[^]` matches any char. Adam, did you mean `/---[^]*?---/g`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: OK, is it working in all regex flavour?

Comment: @Toto It is only ECMAScript flavor compatible.

Comment: @Toto it's also actually pretty useful as `.` doesn't match newline.

Comment: @Walk:Sure, but doesn't work for other regex flavour (PCRE).

Comment: @Toto It is not convenient, but 1) it can be used to check if the regex engine is an ECMAScript powered regex engine, 2) it is the fastest way to match any char in a JS regex since it is a *native built-in* construct. `[\s\S]` and the like are slower. But it is off-topic here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to match any character including new lines. The orignal dashed marker has a space. The following works `/---[^]*?---/g`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

(This should probably be a comment, but you can't have code in'em, so...)

Is it something like this you're after?

```js
function onButton() {

  var msg = $("#AddInfo").val(),
      beginning = 'some stuff ---',
      end = '--- more stuff',
      re = new RegExp(beginning + '\\s*([^]*)\\s*' + end),
      content = re.exec($("#output").html())[1];

  if( msg=='' ) {
    content = '';
  }
  else {
    if( content == '' ) {
      content = '<br/>';
    }
    msg += '<br/>';
  }

  $('#output').html( beginning + content + msg + end );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="AddInfo"/>
  <button type="button" onclick="onButton()">Add</button>
  <br/>
  <span id="output">some stuff --- --- more stuff</span>
</form>
```

Comment: no I want to insert content between the dashed lines as follows `--- [content goes here] ---`. If `$("#AddInfo")` is empty then reset as `--- ---`. If `$("#AddInfo")` is not empty then insert value of `$("#AddInfo")` between the two dashed lines.

Comment: Well, isn't that kind of what my example does? Type text into the edit control and press `Add` and the text is inserted between `some stuff ---` and `--- more stuff`. Press `Add` with the edit control empty and the output is "reset".

Comment: No further comments?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add a quantifier:

```
/---[^]*?---/g
       ^^
```

**Details**

- `---` - 3 `-` chars
- `[^]*?` - any 0+ chars as few as possible, up to the first...
- `---` - 3 `-` chars.